# TcpClient создается, но BeginConnect выбрасывает исключение ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, сеть

В WPF приложении я использую TcpClient для подключения к удаленному серверу.
В приложении есть дерево, при выделении какого-либо узла выполняется код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    TreeView se_TreeView; // предполагаем, что в XAML
    ...
    // Выбор узла дерева
    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        ...
        (se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpClient = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
           (se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpClient.BeginConnect(IP, Port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), tmpObj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // вывод нужной инф в файл.
        }
    }

    // Закрытие приложения
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        if (se_TreeView.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if ((se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpStream != null)
               ((se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpStream.Close();

            if ((se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpClient != null)
               ((se_TreeView.SelectedItem as TCPConnection)._tmpClient.Close();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Есть еще класс который представляет содержимое узла дерева:

```
public class TCPConnection
{
   ...
   public TcpClient _tmpClient;
   public NetworkStream _tmpStream;
   ...
}
```

В общем при каждом запуске приложения и выборе элемента дерева, BeginConnect() выбрасывает исключение:

ObjectDisposedException Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен.
Имя объекта: "System.Net.Sockets.Socket". System    в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   в System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   в ACCCtrl.MainWindow.CS1606CheckConnect(TreeViewLocation tvl, Int32 index) в C:\Users\Documents\CS1606 Asynch\ACCCtrl\MainWindow.xaml.cs:строка 9752

Повторяется стабильно, клиент создается без ошибок, при закрытии приложения ошибок нет.
Но вот заметил, что когда _tmpClient создается, то
_tmpClient.Client.Blocking равен true

Comment: se_TreeView - то самое дерево, элемент которого выбираю

Comment: `_tmpClient.Client.Blocking` и должно быть true, ищите ошибку в другом месте

Comment: Просто непонятно, почему только что созданный клиент оказывается ликвидированным....

Comment: Отличная консультация - ищите ошибку в другом месте )))